# rewrite rule losing destination formatting

Tags: apache-2.4, rewrite

I have stumbled into the world of Apache webservers primarily to have a friendly internal host name for the number of servers running web pages, this has worked fine by repeating the same steps until now.

I have had a peace of software installed called PaperCut to manage all our printing, this comes with a user portal which comes out of the box with a http://servername:1234/user Url.

I have setup a DNS CNAME to point printingportal to my apache server, added a section in my httpd-vhosts.conf with:

```
    ServerName printingportal
    ServerAlias printingportal.domain.org.uk
    ProxyPass / http://servername:1234/user/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://servername:1234/user/

#    ServerAdmin admin@redirectedurl.com

    ErrorLog "logs/printingportal-access.log"
    CustomLog "logs/printingportal-access.log" common
```

Added a PrintingPortal folder in my inetpub directory and in there I have copied from a similar Directory that does the same job and works so have an aspnet_client directory, iis-85.png and iisstart.htm file in there along with web.config.

In web.config there is the following:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Proxy" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="*" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://servername:1234/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Now the issue I have is that when entering the http://servername:1234 Url in a browser, the page I expect is displayed correctly with full colourful background and everything in the right place. If I enter http://printingportal DNS sends that request to the Apache Server, the rewrite rule sends the request to the http://servername:1234 url but the page displayed is missing all the background images, I have a strange black and white angled image as a replacement and the web parts are all shifted around and not in their correct places.

Is there anything I should be adding to the vhost or web.config files to force users to load the full page and formatting?

I have other pages setup the same that work so not sure what I have done wrong. Any help or advice is much appreciated.

Comment: Think I have sorted this myself!
The httpd-vhosts.conf file had the destination path down as http://servername:1234/user/ 
removing user/ and restarting apache sorted the rewrite rule and the page now loads correctly.
#FeelingStupid

Answer (score 0):

Think I have sorted this myself!

The httpd-vhosts.conf file had the destination path down as servername:1234/user
Removing user/ and restarting apache sorted the rewrite rule and the page now loads correctly.

## FeelingStupid